# How to change the background color of a JSpinner (Number model)?

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jspinner

I want to change the background color of my `JSpinner` in red to notify the user an error. My spinner use a number model (no idea if it influence).
I tried a lot of solutions but no one worked.

```
jspinner.setBackground(Color.red);
jspinner.getEditor().getComponent(0).setBackground(Color.red);
```

I understood that I have to access to a specific component of the spinner (like a `JFormattedTextField`) but I don't know how to do...)

### Edit

This should work:

```
JSpinner.NumberEditor jsEditor = (JSpinner.NumberEditor) 
spinner.getEditor(); jsEditor.getTextField().setBackground(Color.red);
```

But it doesn't. Anybody has an idea why?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way to change background color of the jSpinner:

```
SpinnerNumberModel nummodel = new SpinnerNumberModel(5, 0, 10, 1);
JSpinner numspinner = new JSpinner(nummodel);
numspinner.getEditor().getComponent(0).setBackground(Color.green);
                     //getComponent(0) gives you text field
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JComponent editor = spinner.getEditor();
        int n = editor.getComponentCount();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            Component c = editor.getComponent(i);
            if (c instanceof JTextField)
            {
                c.setForeground(Color.red);
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
        }
```

Comment: works (AFAIK its doesn't works for `DateEditor/Model`), e.g. accesible directly from `JSpinner.NumberEditor jsEditor = (JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor();` and 
                `JFormattedTextField textField = jsEditor.getTextField();`

Comment: @mKorbel `JSpinner.NumberEditor jsEditor = (JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor(); and JFormattedTextField textField = jsEditor.getTextField().setBackground(Color.red);` Should work. Is it a bug of swing ?

Comment: @Widea bug is that JSpinner.DateEditor doesn't react to standard settings, getEditorXxx works for most of compound JComponents (e.g. JComboBox, again huge diff. between editable and not)

Comment: @mKorbel But i have a NumberEditor. So i just can't change the background color or i can bypass it ?

Answer (score 0):

be sure you made opaque the JTextField:

```
((JTextField)(connectTimeoutSpn.getEditor().getComponent(0))).setOpaque(true);     
connectTimeoutSpn.getEditor().getComponent(0).setBackground(Color.green);
```